# How can I see dates of previously modified files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a shared folder that I have been using for a while. I frequently upload files and folders in this shared folder along with the other users. However, I recently added 2 more users to share the folder with which updated the last modified date of the folder. I tried looking through the activity log of the shared folder, but all I see is the log spammed with every individual file that has its sharing permissions updated. I tried scrolling all the way down, but the file sharing updates seem infinite and the browser crashed when I scrolled excessively far down. Additionally, I tried using DriveAPI to see if it can show me the list of revisions, but it only works with files and not folders. Is there a way that I can view my previous modified date of the shared folder or am I missing something for the DriveAPI?

Edit: I inputted the `startPageToken` into the `pageToken`, set `supportAllDrives` to false, and `fields` to *.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#changeList",
  "newStartPageToken": "1028106",
  "changes": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

To get the `pageToken` you have to use [Changes: getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) as mentioned on the documentation:

> pageToken | string | The token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response or to the response from the getStartPageToken method.

The call con the `Try this API` for [Changes: getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) should be:

> `supportsAllDrives = false`

Then call the `changes.list` resource. The response has a [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes#resource) resource that contains a [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) resource.

The call on the `Try this API` for [Changes: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) should be:

> `pageToken = "previous page token"`
>
> `restrictToMyDrive = true`
>
> `supportsAllDrives = false`
>
> `fields = *`

Then from the response you can find the parent folder

Comment: Not the best way to get the previous modified date, but it still sort of works since you can view the date and time when you shared the folder. Luckily, I remembered the previous modified time of the folder.

Comment: Did this help you find what you were looking for? If not, can you provide more details on your issue?

Comment: It did help me since I knew the previous modified date of the folder and found the exact date and time when I press the share button for the previous modified date. However, the date doesn't directly show me when the folder was previously modified.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on last comment

Comment: How do I find ```pageToken```? Also, it only says ```driveId``` and not ```folderId```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer in order to clarify

Comment: How do I get ```driveId```? I don't have a shared drive and using the ```folderId``` doesn't work

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I don't see anything in changes when I followed the answer

Comment: Can you update your question showing the result to check if there is something missing in it? Have you tried updating the pageToken?

Comment: After getting the page token and not getting the result, try to create a change (maybe a folder rename) and search with the same token.